# Python receive MySQL Decimal datatype as None

Tags: python, mysql

I have storedproc like:

```
SELECT `MyID`,
        `MyName`,
        `Height`,
        `Units`,
        DATE_FORMAT(DateCreated, '%d %m %Y') AS DateCreated,
        `CreatedBy`,
        DATE_FORMAT(DateUpdated, '%d %m %Y') AS DateUpdated,
        `UpdatedBy`,
        DATE_FORMAT(DateDeleted, '%d %m %Y') AS DateDeleted,
        `DeletedBy`
    FROM `st_mine`
    WHERE DateDeleted IS NULL
    ORDER BY MyName;
```

which Height is `Decimal(8,2)` in my sql

and i have Python call my stored proc and present it as JSON.

the problem here is, Height is always retrieve as NONE

if i change the stored proc into: ``` 15 AS ``Height``, ``` i can retrieve 15.

What's wrong here?

Comment: One obvious question is whether you have verified the data in your table by other means? Are you _sure_ you have decimal values in there?

Comment: Besides the point: You most likely do not want to use Decimal anyway. The data is precise within the database, the database driver will, however, most likely represent it as a float somewhere along the chain. This causes all sorts of fun

Comment: @user2722968 thanks, you're right, changing my datatype to float solved the problem, however still wondering why it didn't catch decimal

Comment: The point was not to use Decimal in order to avoid Float altogether. Name the field `HeightInInches` or something and use a normal Integer. Just like using Decimal and getting floats, using floats directly will cause all kinds of fun like rows missing from a `Height <= 10`-query because their Height as a float is 10.000009; one sees this mistake over and over again in terms of currency/money-values.